# Wireless headset deactivates sound from my speakers

Tags: audio, speakers, wireless-headset

When I plugin the USB-Stick for my Asus Travelite HS-1000W Headset the sound for my speakers is deactivated. Is there a simple solution how to hear the sound from my speakers and my headset simultaneously? It works with my non-wireless headset.

Comment: what OS are you using?  And what do you mean by "USB-Stick?"